# how to change the mouse commands to mobile commands

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile, touch

I have been struggling to understand how to implement the mobile input system instead of mouse or example keyboard commands on my code with a simple touch
lets suppose I have to throw an object a script that works on Pc is this :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ThrowObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Transform playerCam;
    public float throwForce = 10;
    bool hasPlayer = false;
    bool beingCarried = false;
    public AudioClip[] soundToPlay;
    private AudioSource audio;
    public int dmg;
    private bool touched = false;

    void Start()
    {
        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, player.position);
        if (dist <= 2.5f)
        {
            hasPlayer = true;
        }
        else
        {
            hasPlayer = false;
        }
        if (hasPlayer && Input.GetButtonDown("Use"))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
            transform.parent = playerCam;
            beingCarried = true;
        }
        if (beingCarried)
        {
            if (touched)
            {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
                transform.parent = null;
                beingCarried = false;
                touched = false;
            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                {
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
                    transform.parent = null;
                    beingCarried = false;
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(playerCam.forward * throwForce);
                RandomAudio();
                }
                else if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
                {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
                    transform.parent = null;
                beingCarried = false;
                }
            }
        }
    void RandomAudio()
    {
        if (audio.isPlaying){
            return;
                }
        audio.clip = soundToPlay[Random.Range(0, soundToPlay.Length)];
        audio.Play();

    }
   void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        if (beingCarried)
        {
            touched = true;
        }
    }
    }
```

How can I change this so I will use it only on mobile - with not the mouse..
I have been searching in internet /youtube for many different things but hard to find on about it.
Thanks in advance.
I was searching in internet and youtube videos example how to create mobile pick up or throw system just by touch but nothing I have been found nor videos for those.I tryed a lot of time to change the codes but I didn't managed to.

Comment: Have you tried Input.GetTouch?
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html

Comment: mouse inputs are emulated on mobile, they should work just fine, as long as you don't need multi touch or touch state tracking